# can I configure Java logging to make use of Spring Boot logging?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My use case is as follows. I'm developing a large spring based application and we are using spring boot logging throughout. However, for various reasons I need to use a third-party library that uses java.util.Logger in its internals. This causes the two separate loggers to both send their output to our console.

I've found many examples on how to configure spring boot logging to use java logging as its output, but I haven't been able to determine how to go the other way.

The library in question - JLibModbus - includes API access to set it's logging level or to turn it off, but I don't see any way to actually tell it to use a different logger. Presumably this should be possible. I'm hoping that someone else has already done this.

(Actually I'm working in Kotlin, not Java, but any answer that works in one I should be able to convert to the other.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to configure the logging of a lib which uses Java Util Logging.

Spring Boot comes already with a [managed dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d9af7cec141190fb32e20de6a64c2d3b03b644e4/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L1465) which helps you to fix your issue.

Please add or verify that you've already added the JUL to SLF4J bridge:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please check also, that you put your logger configurations in the [correct config file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration), especially referencing:

- Logback – logback-spring.xml, …
- Log4j2 – log4j2-spring.xml, …
- JDK (Java Util Logging) – logging.properties

Comment: First, I want to thank you for this answer - it does exactly what I was hoping it would do. To make it work in my environment (configured using gradle), I needed to add the line `runtime("org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j")` to my dependancies list.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me at least, it didn't solve my actual problem. In digger a bit deeper it seems the library I'm using isn't using java logging but is just manually writing to the standard output device. Annoying and I will probably log (pun intended) it to the author. But your answer did exactly what it was supposed to, so I'm going to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yeah, just saw your new issue in Github. That is really a mess, just logging to the stdout. However it should not be a big deal for the maintainer to switch this to JUL or even better SLF4J. May be the jlibmodbus community accepts pull requests so you could contribute your preferred solution. :-)

Comment: I suppose we are getting off topic here, but my preferred solution would actually be JUL over SLF4J, then relying on a bridge when used in Spring. My key reasoning is that I don't like having to add libraries I wouldn't otherwise care about in order to use one that I need. Not every application I write will necessarily be a Spring app.

Comment: The first link mentioned in the answer does not work any more. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @user674669, updated this one.